# In flex how do I pass data retrieved from a remote object service to a modules interface?

Tags: apache-flex, module, blazeds, remoteobject

I found at [this Adobe tutorial](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=rpc_httpws_12.html) a nice "RemoteService" class that creates a RemoteObject and contains the functions for handling the result and fault events. If I wanted to use this approach, how could I pass the data from the result handler to interfaces that modules from the main application could use?

I could put the RemoteService/RemoteObject in the modules, but (in my opinion- and I could be wrong) the best design seems to be using the remote calls in the main app and passing the data along to the modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're correct -- have the remote calls in the main app if other parts of the app will need the data.

To get data into the module, just set a property of the module to the data. So a result handler in the main app sets `myModule.someObject = event.result.someObject.`

To get data from the module back to the app, dispatch an event.  This way the module is loosely coupled to whoever its host is.